# Hover Tooltip stopped working in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-debugging

Was working on a new solution, new project in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web.  For some reason, the tooltip info that normally appears for variables and objects when I hit a breakpoint while debugging is no longer working, even for my older solutions/projects that used to work fine.  The breakpoints work fine, but no info at all appears when I hover over variables, etc.

Have no idea if this has anything to do with it, but I did set this new solution/project to ASP 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repairing Visual Studio did not work.  I uninstalled and reinstalled Visual Studio.  My problem now seems to be resolved.